# Spring-Websocket: Send Updates to Subscribers when condition is met

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-websocket, sockjs, java-websocket

I have the following method on a Spring @Controller:

```
@MessageMapping("/comment/{id}")
@SendTo("/topic/conversation/{id}")
public OperationResult<Comment> comment(Comment comment) throws Exception {

    //call @Service to add comment
    OperationResult<Comment> operationResult = commentService.comment(comment);

    return operationResult;}
```

This will send updates to all the subscribers even if the operation was not successful (operationResult.success == false).

**NB:** OperationResult has a boolean field called 'success' to indicate whether the operation was successful or not.

**Question:**
I want to find out how can I only send updates to subscribers if the operation was successful (without throwing an exception) and ensure that the client that sent the comment always gets the **operationResult**

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a way to only send updates based on a condition

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

@MessageMapping("/comment/{id}" )
public OperationResult<Comment> comment(Comment comment) throws Exception {

    OperationResult<Comment> operationResult = new OperationResult<>();
    conversationService.comment(operationResult, comment);

    if (operationResult.isSuccess()) {
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/conversation/"+operationResult.getReturnedObject().getConversation().getId(), operationResult);
    }
    return operationResult;
}
```

This however does not allow me to return the **operationResult** to the client.

**UPDATE:**

To allow the client to get the **operationResult** I replaced the `@MessageMapping` with `@RequestMapping`. So the client has to make a normal ajax call to submit a comment.

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

@RequestMapping("/comment" )
public OperationResult<Comment> comment(@RequestBody Comment comment) throws Exception {

    OperationResult<Comment> operationResult = new OperationResult<>();
    conversationService.comment(operationResult, comment);

    if (operationResult.isSuccess()) {
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/conversation/"+operationResult.getReturnedObject().getConversation().getId(), operationResult);
    }
    return operationResult;
}
```